# How to open multiple instances of an application using swift for macOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

does anyone know how I would be able to open multiple instances of an application for macOS (like google chome or safari) from my app using swift?  I am currently using

```
let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = app.executableURL
    task.arguments = windows // windows is an array of urls
     try? task.run()
```

However, when this code runs again to make a new instance of google chrome or another app the tabs (windows is an array of urls) the urls are appended to the same window and not a new one.

Comment: **"open multiple instances of an application"** You meant multiple windows

Comment: I mean windows/instances and not tabs

Comment: Windows are not instances (for any meaning of "instance"). To open a new window, you generally create a new NSWindowController or use NSDocumentController, depending on your architecture . You don't create a new process. Creating a completely separate process is very rare, and what Chrome and Safari are doing isn't anything like what you're describing (they create a process per tab for issolation, but they don't just launch the entire application again).

Comment: If you want to implement what Chrome and Safari do, then you should look at XPC services, but this is a very advanced technique and not something you should do if you just want a second window. If you're using SwiftUI, look at Scenes.